# How to load different UIViews based on different data after segueing from an UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I've an `UITableView` which loads data from a database file. It has different sections. I have managed to design a custom `UITableViewCell` programmatically. When I touch a cell, I'm segueing to an `UIViewController`. The segue is added from the Interface Builder. Now, I need to load different contents (i.e. `UILabel`,`UIButton`) in the new `UIViewController` based on the section number of the `UITableView`. For more visualization, I'm adding images below.

How to accomplish this? Should I use custom `UIViewController` subclass for each action? Or is there any easier way to do this?

## 1st view

[image: view 1]

## 2nd view

[image: view 2]

## 3rd view

[image: view 3]

Comment: Do you mean you're segueing to a UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, I'm segueing to an `UIViewController` @NiñoScript

Comment: I edited your question to reflect that. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code, you can use the `prepareForSegue` method, check the identifier, and pass the next `UIViewController` the relevant data.

If the interface is different for each kind cell, then you should use different `UIViewController`s for each kind of interface. All of this can be done through the storyboard, by "ctrl-dragging" from each prototype cell to a different controller.

---

If you don't want to use different prototype cells for different data. (Which would make this very easy to do with the Storyboard), then instead of segueing through the storyboard, call the segue via code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of your `UITableView delegate`. Like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("some_segue_id", sender: self)
    case 1:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("another_segue_id", sender: self)
    default:
        print("not a known section")
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is, I'm using just one reusable cell. Contents are different as I'm fetching them from a database. And I want to segue to an `UIView` or `UIViewController` depending on the section number of the selected cell

Comment: You could easily use more reusable cells, that would also make it easier to change the interface of each kind of data if you ever want to. But if you don't want to, I added a code example to my answer above.

Comment: Okay. But how to add more segues? I've added one segue from the `UITableViewCell' to `UIViewController` by control-dragging in the storyboard and given it an identifier. But I'm not able to add more segues from one cell to different `UIViewController` scene.

Comment: Delete that segue, and add many segues from the `UITableViewController` to different `UIViewController`s. And then perform the segue with the code I gave you instead of with the storyboard (that's what I meant with "instead of segueing through the storyboard")